# How to Modify Drupal 7 Bootstrap Theme Title?

Tags: 7, theming

I cannot find where to modify the title from:

**SiteName | SiteSlogan**

to

**SiteName - SiteSlogan**

I am using the https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap theme.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing is come under $head_title variable on html.tpl.php.

So for changing this you need to override [template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)

where replace statement

`$variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', $head_title);`

with

`$variables['head_title'] = implode(' - ', $head_title);`

I am assuming you have enough idea about overriding of templates.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect. I didn't realize it was being set in the drupal core includes/theme.inc file.